# Swift Put String to Array from one to all letters

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

I want to programmatically add a string to an array but from the first letter to the last. But not every letter separately.

something like this:

[image]

I tried this:

```
let username = "Julius" //(1)
var name = "" //(2) 
var i:Int! = 0 
while i != username.count { 
    i += 1 
    //get nth(i) char of String(1) 
    //add char to String (2) 
    //add to Array
}
```

Comment: you should try something first.

Comment: Please provide any code you have working towards this so we can see where to help guide you.

Comment: A simple for loop will do the job. You have the number of items (number of letters), you can iterate then. You can substring with `dropLast()`...  Did you try anything?

Comment: I tried this: 

 let username = "Julius" //(1)
        var name = "" //(2)
        var i:Int! = 0
        while i != username.count {
            i += 1
            //get nth(i) char of String(1)
            //add char to String (2)
            //add to Array
        }

Answer (score 1):

```swift
let string = "Julius"

// ["", "J", "Ju", "Jul", "Juli", "Juliu", "Julius"]
(1...string.count).map(string.prefix)
```

or

```swift
string.enumerated().map { string.prefix($0.offset + 1) }
```

…which skips a string traversal, but is uglier. Probably not worth it.

```swift
extension String {
  var : [Substring] { (1...count).map(prefix) }
}

// "", "", "", ""]

"".
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
var str = "julius"
var nameArray = [String]()
var item = ""
for char in Array(str) {
     item += String(char)
    nameArray.append(item)
}
print(nameArray)
```

**Edit**

```
let str = "julius"
    var nameArray = [String]()
    var item = ""
    for char in str {
         item += String(char)
        nameArray.append(item)
    }
    print(nameArray)
```

Comment: "Array(str)" is unecessary. You can just do `for char in str`. `String` already conforms to `Sequence`, directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`, it will iterate over characters and give you access to all iterated characters :

```
let usernameAsArray = "julius".reduce([]) { $0 + [($0.last ?? "") + "\($1)"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`. Please refer apple official docs on  [reduce(*:*:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce) method

## Code:

```
"Julius".reduce([]) { $0 + [($0.last ?? "") + "\($1)"] }
```

Answer (score -1):

Give this function a go.

```
func addLetters(string: String)->[String]{
    var stringArray = [String]()

    for (i, s) in string.enumerated(){

        if i == 0 {
            stringArray.append(String(s))
        }
        else{
            stringArray.append(stringArray[i - 1] + String(s))
        }

    }
    print(stringArray)
    return stringArray
}

addLetters(string: "Julius")
//Print: ["J", "Ju", "Jul", "Juli", "Juliu", "Julius"]
```

Comment: I've tested this answer over and over again and it is correct. Can someone please explain why my answer is marked wrong? Or correct this if it's marked wrong as a mistake.