# Swift split String into array

Tags: ios, swift, string

I have a string with no spaces I would like to turn the string into an array.

Let's say the string is "guru1", I would like my array to be ["g", "gu", "gur", "guru", "guru1"]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You surely tried *something.* Don't hesitate to show your attempt so that it does not look like a “Write the code for me!” question!

Comment: Didn't I see the same question a few days ago? Any attempt with a for loop would be a good improvement on the question. We ask for attempts.

Comment: @Larme I didn't try a for loop tbh I'll give that a shot thx.

Comment: @Larme [Yes you did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61252106/swift-put-string-to-array-from-one-to-all-letters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` :

```
"guru1".reduce([]) { $0 + [($0.last ?? "") + "\($1)"] }
```